# How to evaluate the column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to convert string mins to secs as mentioned data below

Example:

```
    mysql> select mins  from mins;
+------------------+
| mins             |
+------------------+
| 10 min 24.16 sec |
| 4 min 55.74 sec  |
| 2 min 10.72 sec  |
| 1 min 3.52 sec   |

**Expected output:**

+------------------+
| secs             |
+------------------+
| 624.16 sec |
| 295.74 sec  |
| 130.72 sec |
| 63.52 sec |
```

How to achieve it using mysql functions.Please  help on this.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `substring_index` and implicit conversion:

```
select ((substring_index(mins, ' min ', 1) + 0) * 60 +
        substring_index(mins, ' min ', -1) + 0
       ) as secs
```